# Return the opposite results of LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

If I would have 2 tables

```
Table A   Table B
ID, ABC   ABC
1, A      A
2, B      A
3, C      C
4, D      E
5, E      F
```

How do I get this result

```
Table Result
2, B
4, D
```

The following query needs to be adjusted, but I dont know how

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.abc = B.abc
```

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11093

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close.  Just add a `where` clause:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     B
     ON A.abc = B.abc
WHERE B.abc IS NULL;
```

A more traditional approach uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.abc = a.abc);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50e94) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating that the first works.

Comment: I dont get it, why is a left outer join not sufficient to display all the results. https://www.google.nl/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLgvbg5bvNAhVrJcAKHV56AJ0QjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F6294778%2Fmysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins&psig=AFQjCNHLStQc7_DpTjFOh15F5lC8v2Wj9A&ust=1466690427307566 Why doesnt it happen like it said in the picture?

Comment: and what's the difference between Left outer join and left join?

Comment: This doesn't provide me with the correct result. It shows me the complete values of A.

Comment: @Adam . . . `left outer join` and `left join` are the same thing.  If these queries do not work for you, then the values in the two tables are not what they seem.  In other words, what look like matches in `B` are really different -- perhaps because of hidden characters (such as spaces) or characters that look very similar).

Comment: Okey thanks for clearing that up. im sorry im really stupid, I used ON A.abc = B.abc AND B.abc IS NULL. Found the error. Thanks for helping me out!